# Translate Date Time CEST CET (OSM timestamp) in to CET YYYY-MM-dd (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, datetime

I need the date in YYYY-MM-DD (CET) from an OSM timestamp with mixed (CEST/CET) dates. The time is not necessary. Finally, I just want to show all records that are 7 days old (as expression to filter or style).

Here my date-times:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field already is in datetime format. You can see this because its alligned right. If it was a string, it would be alligned left. To filter for records of the last 7 days you can use:

```
osm_timestamp >= (now() - to_interval('7 day'))
```

If you want to create a datefield without the time you can use:

```
to_date("osm_timestamp")
```

To change the format the Datetime is displayed in, go to layer properties -> attributes form, choose the field and change the field format or widget display:

[image]

This should work since 3.16 as [stated in an QGIS issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31097).