# Changing timezone of features attribute

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, widget, datetime, time-zone

When adding a feature I am adding a Datetime field to the layer (its of type memory layer). I set up the widget to also add the timezone:

[image]

But: when adding a feature it does not let me change the timezone. I can mark the part of the timezone but can not change anything here. This is also not possible afterwards in the attribute table. I can change year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond. But not the timezone.

The help says:

[image]

> ISO 8601 extended format: either yyyy-MM-dd for dates or
> yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss (e.g. 2017-07-24T15:46:29) or with a time-zone
> suffix (Z for UTC otherwise an offset [+|-]HH:mm) where appropriate
> for combined dates and times.

How can I change the timezone of a feature via widget or attribute table in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Worth a feature request?

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't find an universal way (OS-based) to do what you want, here is a workaround:

[image]

where in the expression

```
datetime_from_epoch( 
epoch( now())
 +5*3600*1000
)
```

the value `5` is the number of hours you want to offset your timezone to.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to only change the time, but not the timezone. I still have CEST and cannot change it. Its just the correct time in the wrong timezone then which can be very misleading.

Comment: Yes: it changes the time relative to your PC's time zone. Since the `CEST` is maintained, it effectively equates to changing the time. Can you then make an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually I am not trying to do something specific. This question arose while experimenting with the answer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442047/translate-date-time-cest-cet-osm-timestamp-in-to-cet-yyyy-mm-dd-qgis/442048. So basically this question is just about "how to set or change the timezone of a features attribute".

Comment: I see. I think however that what you are shown as an output is just a representation of an internal timestamp (epoch) referenced to your time zone. For example: think of a certain value of the field that you created at `14:00 (CEST)`, a colleague in NYC would see `08:00 (EDT)` and both would be right and mean the same universal time. So just changing the "label" does not sense to me (unless you want to alter the actual / underlying timestamp). I hope that makes sense :)