# QGIS Time error: UTC = Australian Central Standard Time

Tags: qgis, datetime

```
QGIS version 3.26.3-Buenos Aires
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
```

I originally made a GPS waypoint approx lunch time in central Australia.

In QGIS I import a gpx file with waypoint

```
<time>2023-04-23T01:12:40Z</time>
```

The resultant feature's attribute table has time:

```
23/4/23 01:12:40 (ACST)
```

So somewhere is an awareness that I live in Australian Central Standard Time,
but the calculation hasn't been done.

Is this something I can fix or a bug?

Comment: May be related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442060/changing-timezone-of-features-attribute Probably worth a request/report on github.